# How can I fetch the last N rows, WITHOUT ordering the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables with multiple million rows and need to fetch the last rows of specific ID's

for example the last row which has device_id = 123 AND the last row which has device_id = 1234

because the tables are so huge and ordering takes so much time, is it possible to select the last 200 without ordering the table and then just order those 200 and fetch the rows I need.

How would I do that?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**

My PostgreSQL version is 9.2.1

sample data:

```
time                      device_id         data       data ....
"2013-03-23 03:58:00-04" | "001EC60018E36" | 66819.59 | 4.203
"2013-03-23 03:59:00-04" | "001EC60018E37" | 64277.22 | 4.234
"2013-03-23 03:59:00-04" | "001EC60018E23" | 46841.75 | 2.141
"2013-03-23 04:00:00-04" | "001EC60018E21" | 69697.38 | 4.906
"2013-03-23 04:00:00-04" | "001EC600192524"| 69452.69 | 2.844
"2013-03-23 04:01:00-04" | "001EC60018E21" | 69697.47 | 5.156
....
```

See [SQLFiddle of this data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5710a)

So if device_id = 001EC60018E21
I would want the most recent row with that device_id.
It is a grantee that the last row with that device_id is the row I want, but it may or may not be the last row of the table.

Comment: The last 200 rows are guaranteed to have the last rows where id = 123 and id = 1234

Comment: If you know the IDs, why would you bother fetching the entire table? A strategically placed RDBMS index would solve the problem just fine.

Comment: It's always best to show your PostgreSQL version, sample data and expected results so we don't have to create a test case for you.

Comment: the id's as they are in my example are not row id's they are id's for a certain data grouping. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: if you know how many rows in the table, you could use `offset`, but you would need to run `explain` to see if it actually bought you anything

Comment: the problem is, there are about 20 new entries every minute and even more in the future.

Comment: Have you tried creating a reverse order index on the DATE field? This *should* speed up your 'ORDER BY date DESC' clause. Then you can use SELECT with LIMIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to get the "last" row for each device_id looks like this.

```
select *
from Table1 
inner join (select device_id, max(time) max_time
            from Table1
            group by device_id) T2
   on Table1.device_id = T2.device_id
  and Table1.time = T2.max_time;
```

Getting the "last" 200 device_id numbers without using an ORDER BY isn't really practical, but it's not clear why you might want to do that in the first place. If 200 is an arbitrary number, then you can get better performance by taking a subset of the table that's based on an arbitrary time instead.

```
select *
from Table1 
inner join (select device_id, max(time) max_time
            from Table1
            where time > '2013-03-23 12:03'
            group by device_id) T2
on Table1.device_id = T2.device_id
and Table1.time = T2.max_time;
```

Comment: Funny timing, same query within a minute of each other, editing concurrently

Comment: @CraigRinger: Hey, if I'm writing the same SQL that you are, I'm putting that on my résumé.

Comment: Thank you Mike Sherrill 'Catcall' and Craig Ringer! I need a little time to digest the brilliant ideas, and yes 200 was an arbitrary number and you are right an arbitrary data is better.

Comment: Thank you, both of you! That query works well, it is still slow, but already a lot faster than what it was before!

Comment: How would I make the cut-off data the last five minutes for example?

Comment: I just found the answer to that: current_timestamp - interval '5' minute

Comment: Slow? Look at Craig Ringer's advice about indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd create a composite index on `device_id` and descending `time`:

```
CREATE INDEX table1_deviceid_time ON table1("device_id","time" DESC);
```

then I'd use a subquery to find the highest `time` for each `device_id` and join the subquery results against the main table on `device_id` and `time` to find the relevant data, eg:

```
SELECT t1."device_id", t1."time", t1."data", t1."data1"
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t1b."device_id", max(t1b."time") FROM Table1 t1b GROUP BY t1b."device_id"
) last_ids("device_id","time") 
ON (t1."device_id" = last_ids."device_id" 
    AND t1."time" = last_ids."time");
```

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ddc2e/3).

It might be helpful to maintain a trigger-based materialized view of the highest timestamp for each device ID. However, this will cause concurrency issues if most than one connection can insert data for a given device ID due to the connections fighting for update locks. It's also a pain if you don't know when new device IDs will appear as you have to do an upsert - something that's very inefficient and clumsy. Additionally, the extra write load and autovacuum work created by the summary table may not be worth it; it might be better to just pay the price of the more expensive query.

BTW, `time` is a terrible name for a column because it's a built-in data type name. Use something more appropriate if you can.

Comment: It might come to that point where I need to do that. And 'time' as a name cannot be changed, there are too many dependent scripts already, but I will keep that in mind. Thank you for your help!